# Why can't I use While(1) in C#?

Tags: c#

I know this has probably already been answered somewhere, I just can't find it. Why doesn't C# allow me to use `while(1)`? I know that 'There is no conversion between the bool type and other types' in C# but why? What are the reasons for this, when in c++ it's perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I think you should accept danben's answer if it helped you.

Comment: I will but I have to wait 10 minutes.

Comment: @manneorama   This question has only been live for 14 minutes - anon is encouraged to accept an answer only if it is correct and there are no other proposals that are more acceptable. While people are still answering there is no rush to accept an answer

Comment: have you ever read any documentation related to C# at all?

Comment: @Shaydariv - Is this directed at me? Yes, i've read plenty of documentation relating to c# - I use the language everyday. Thumbing through documentation would have taken forever, isn't this what stackoverflow is for?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is to keep programmers from accidentally doing something they did not want to do.

Consider this common pitfall in C/C++:

```
int x = getValue();
if (x = 10) {
  // do something
}
```

This will compile and run, but produce unexpected results (the programmer likely meant to check that `x` equals `10`, not assign to `x` -- otherwise, why would he need the test at all?  It will always evaluate to `true`).

By forcing conditionals to be of boolean type, you avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks danben, this is the answer i was looking for.

Comment: -1: If that was the aim, then it would be a much better way to simply forbid assignments in the if-conditionals.

Comment: -1? Why? He explained why it isn't allowed in C#, he had nothing to do with it been implemented this way.

Comment: @Luther Blissett: Please reread my answer.  I think you did not see the first sentence, where I state that the *general* intent is to avoid pitfalls by making the programmer's intent explicit.  Following, I provided ONE example of what can go wrong if non-booleans are allowed where conditional expressions are expected.  Your "counter-argument" is flawed; a better one (if you still think I am wrong) would be to show that there is some better reason for this.  However, if you can only come up with other pitfalls then you are just supporting my argument.

Comment: Any .NET type with a user defined implicit conversion to bool would still be assignable in an if() conditional. So removing the conversion from int->bool does not tackle the problem all.

Comment: @Luther, I think you should take up your issue with the C# dev team, not danben.  All he did was explain how C# works, what its limitations are, etc.  Why would you say this is wrong? An utterly incorrect example of how NOT to downvote someone.

Comment: I have no issues with the C#dev team. Because the C#dev team did not intent to prevent accidental assigments in the if() clause, as I already pointed out. danbens answer is misleading, because it uses an *unintended* consequence of a design decision to answer a question *why a design decision has been made in the first place*. So, if anon is okay with that, good for him. But the problem is now, that SO will retrieve this "answer", checked and +16 upvoted for next user who has the same question and wants an insight in the why's and woe's of C#.

Comment: @Luther Blissett - I don't see where you are getting the idea that I suggested the intent was to prevent assignment within a conditional.  I still think you have not understood my answer.

Comment: I don't see where you are getting the idea that I suggested your answer was "*to prevent assignment within a conditional*". I still think you have not understood my answer. I know that you said nothing about the intent to remove the conversion **and that's exactly why I don't like this answer**.

Comment: "I know that you said nothing about the intent to remove the conversion" - yes, I did.  It is the first sentence of my answer, which I have continually requested that you read.  However, if you decide to read it and are sure that it is not the correct answer, then please post the correct one.

Answer (score 8):

> What are the reasons for this, when in
>   c++ it's perfectly acceptable.

Because C# isn't C++. The languages share a similar syntax but they're distinct. C# isn't a successor to C++, it's an entirely new language.

> I know that 'There is no conversion
>   between the bool type and other types'
>   in c# but why?

Why should there be? There's no *logical* conversion I can think of between an integer and a boolean value.

> Why doesn't c# allow me to use while(1)?

Is there really something that wrong about using `while(true)`? =) On a slightly more serious note, `while(...)` is basically saying, "whilst the condition described inside the brackets evaluates to true, perform the following action(s)". There's really no logical way for the C# compiler to convert *1* to either *true* or *false*, hence it doesn't let you use it.

Comment: "Why should there be? There's no logical conversion I can think of between an integer and a boolean value."

{bool, false,true, x and y , not x} is ismorphic to { int, 0, 1, x * y, 1-x}

Comment: @Luther ... that's, almost always, an implementation detail. I'm fairly sure that someone could *theoretically* create an implementation of the CLR that used an in memory representation of bool where true was stored as the 0x00101010 and was represented by any value which is *not* 0x00101010. A bool doesn't *have* to be represented in memory as 1 or 0..... (I, personally, think that 0x00101010 as a representation for 'true' is quite a good one =)

Comment: @Luther: Not in Visual Basic or C#. In fact, Visual Basic *does* define a default conversion from boolean to integer that is different than yours. An integer is not a boolean unless someone defines a conversion - true/false may map fairly well to 1/0 for many purposes but that doesn't make it a law of nature.

Answer (score 4):

You answered your own question: "There is no conversion between the bool type and other types." The C# compiler does this to help enforce correctness and avoid common mistakes, like putting an assignment expression inside a while that always evaluates to true (using one equals sign instead of two).

Answer (score 1):

if `0` is `false` then which one should be true, `1` or `-1`? The first is what is assumed to be correct, but the second actully has all its bits set and is equal to `~0` (not false).

Comment: The distinction here is between an explicit `true` value and a *truthy* value; there is no "right" answer to your question of what SHOULD represent a truthy value, but in C and C++ it is defined to be anything non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

It forces a boolean evaluation. Similarly, in order to protect assignment in an `if` statement's condition  from providing a boolean value.

```
if (x = y)
```

this assignment will be evaluated  in the sense that "did x get assigned y" - as opposed to "is x equal to y" - not what the programmer likely intended.

If you want an infinitely looping condition us `while(true)`; if you want to loop while a variable is a specific value, set a Bool to true prior to the loop:

```
Bool valid = (x == 42);
while(valid){//...
```